# python: optional arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I would like to obtain a function that works like this:

```
operations(a, b) = a + b
operations(a, b, operation = 'subtraction') = a - b
operations(a, b, operation = 'multiplication') = a * b
operations(a, b, operation = 'division') = a / b
```

Operation should be an optional argument that specifies the operation to be performed. By default, it should consider the addition operation.

I was not able to achieve this using *args and **kwargs, probably because I didn't actually get how they work.

Thank you

Edit: Sorry I was making a stupid mistake. Thanks anyway.

Comment: in comparison to my answer you are not using `==` but `=` witch creates the sinax error (inside a if statements)

Comment: Yes, I noticed it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use optional arguments:

```
def operation(a, b, tp = "addition"):
    if tp == "subtraction":
        return a - b
    if tp == "division":
        return a / b
    if tp == "multiplication":
        return a * b
    return a + b

print(operation(10, 20) == 30)
print(operation(10, 20, "subtraction") == -10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to provide a default value for the parameter.

```
def operations(a, b, operation='addition'):
    ...
```

---

`*args` lets you collect arbitrary positional arguments in a single tuple named `args`.

```
def foo(*args):
    print(args)

>>> foo(1, 2)
(1, 2)
```

`**kwargs` works the same, but for keyword arguments, collecting them in a `dict`:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

>>> foo(a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

`**kwargs` is typically used when you just need to pass an unknown set of arguments on to another function call. In your case here, you know that an argument named `operation` is to be used, so you can specify it by name in the parameter list.

---

You can also *require* that it be passed as a keyword argument, like so:

```
def operations(a, b, *, operation='addition'):
    ...
```

Now `operations(a, b, 'subtraction')` is illegal; it must be called like `operations(a, b)` or `operations(a, b, operation='subtraction')`.