# How do I implement **kwargs to omit arguments in a function?

Tags: python, function, arguments

## I'm looking for someone who can explain a solution as simply as possible

When making a function, I was wondering if it was possible to optionalize certain arguments in a function. Usually I would get an error saying `missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg1'`. using `**kwargs` may work, any way someone can explain this to me?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
def myFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(arg1)
    print(arg2)
    print(arg3)

myFunc(arg3)
```

Comment: What do you want your output to be given the code you posted?

Comment: `def myFunc(**kwargs)`, then access the arguments by indexing the `kwargs` dictionary.

Comment: See https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-keyword-arguments-in-python

Comment: @quamrana I just don't want to get an error

Comment: I think that is a given. But what about the output from your function?

Comment: FWIW, the answer you accepted is basically the same as [the one suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67402942/python-optional-arguments) [the last time you posted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76782155/how-to-not-use-certain-arguments-in-a-functional)…

Comment: @deceze but I didn't quite understand that answer at the time, and that is why I wanted a simple explanation for my question. Why is everyone on this site so rude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all of the args keyword args:

```
def myFunc(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    ...
```

Then call the function with as many or as few of the args as you like:

```
myFunc(arg1="hello", arg2="apple")
myFunc(arg2="goodbye")
myFunc(arg3="abc")
```

Comment: For clarity: what you have done is not define “all as keyword args”. The arguments can still all be passed either positionally or by keyword. You’ve given them *default values*, which means they can be omitted. You then explicitly pass them by name when calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I implement **kwargs to omit args in a function?

`**kwargs` collects *keyword* arguments that do not correspond arguments explicitly named in the function definition.  This is a fair way to accept, and possibly ignore, *extra* keyword arguments, but it does not provide for the caller to omit arguments. Note also that the name `kwargs` is just a convention.  It is the `**` that is functionally important; the name can be anything.

The analogous syntax for positional arguments is `*args`, but again, this does not provide for callers to omit arguments; rather, it provides for callers to provide *extra* positional arguments.

In your particular example, it seems that `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` all have equivalent significance, so you could consider something like this:

```
def myFunc(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

That will accept any number of positional arguments, including zero, and print each one given.  You could even generalize that to

```
def myFunc(*args, **kwargs):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
    for arg in kwargs.values():
        print(arg)
```

, which prints both positional and keyword argument values.

But in your example, you suggest

```
myFunc(arg3)
```

, and if the significance to `myFunc()` of the third argument is different than the significance of the first then there's no way for that to work as you want.  How can Python distinguish it from `myFunc(arg1)`?  But you can support that by

1. Giving some or all arguments default values.  `None` is often a good choice for this purpose.  AND
2. Expecting the caller to exercise this case by use of a keyword argument.

Example:

```
def myFunc(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    if arg1 is not None:
        print(f'arg1 is {arg1}')
    if arg2 is not None:
        print(f'arg2 is {arg2}')
    if arg3 is not None:
        print(f'arg3 is {arg3}')

myFunc(arg3='foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `fo(*argv)` if the elements are like a list  and `fo(**kwargs)` if you want key-value pairs (dictionary).

An example

```
def fo(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print(value)

fo(name="Alice", name2="Bob")
```

will print you

```
Alice
Bob
```

You can do the same thing with

```
def fo(*args):
    value in args:
        print(value)

fo("Alice", "Bob")
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to make arguments optional would be to define a default.
If you set the default to `None`, you could then proceed by checking if they are `None` and handle them accordingly.

```
def myFunc(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    print(arg1)
    print(arg2)
    print(arg3)

myFunc(arg3=arg3)
```

This doesn't work with positional arguments though, because myfunc(arg3) would assign the value of arg3 to arg1 in the context of your scope.
To make sure this doesn't happen, you could enforce keyword arguments by using the "*".

```
def myFunc(*, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    print(arg1)
    print(arg2)
    print(arg3)
```

this would raise an Exception when you are calling `myFunc(arg3)` without using the keyword.
Of course, `**kwargs` would work as well. You could then use `kwargs.get("arg1", None)` to get a default value of None (or something else).